# What is the meaning of `light my fire` in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, american-english

What is the meaning of **light my fire** in this sentence:

> You light my red fire. Hot white, and blue.

American Flag?

The context is the song *On Our Way* by Lana Del Rey:

> *You, ooh-ooh-ooh
>
>   You light my red fire, babe
>
>   Hot white and blue
>
>   I, I think that you
>
>   I think you're so cool, babe
>
>   Lovin' everything you do*

The full lyrics can be found [here](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858889043/).

Comment: I have no idea what the colors refer to.  I suppose there's an off-chance it's related to flame temperature: red hot < white hot < blue hot, I suppose.

Comment: Can you tell us where you found the sentence? Quite often, context is the key to understanding. Talking about _fire_ in a poem or song is often quite different than talking about _fire_ in a chemistry textbook, and different yet again from a camping pamphlet, or a forestry guide. We may need more information to answer this question definitively. (I've gone ahead and modified the question for you, but next time you'll have a better idea of what to do.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Light my fire" is a metaphorical way to say something along the lines of, "Get me worked up" or, "Turn me on" or, "Inspire me". The phrase has been rather famous in musical circles for decades now, thanks to [the song by The Doors of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_My_Fire).

In this context, it seems like the lyricist is playing off the expression "Red, white and blue" (which, in the US, can mean "patriotic") by saying "Hot white and blue" instead, and moving the word *red* to the previous line. As snailboat mentioned in a comment, the colors are probably also related to flame temperatures. The term *red hot* can take on [a lot of different meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hot) – it can mean *spicy, sizzling,* or *burning*, and can be used by scientists to describe stars in the galaxy, by culinary experts to describe the food on your plate, or by lovers to describe a steamy relationship – and probably a host of other things as well.

What we've got then, is a mixed bag of metaphors, euphamisms, and expressions all designed to let the singer express deep emotional excitement and affection. The short answer? Somebody is head-over-heels in love.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted to know. So it's not related to US flag?

Comment: It's sort of related. I doubt that line would have made it into the song if "Red, white, and blue" wasn't a common expression meaning "All things American," and those three colors wouldn't be a saying for "All things American" if those weren't the colors on the flag. Compare and contrast with the opening line of _Fortunate Son_: _"Some folks are born made to wave the flag / Ooh, they're red, white and blue..."_